# Regex space and backspace

Tags: regex

I have a description field working with this regex

```
/^(?![\s\S]*www)(?![\s\S]*http)(?![\s\S]*@)(?![\s\S]*\.com)(?![\s\S]*\.pt)(?![\s\S]*co\.uk)[\s\S]+$/i
```

When I try to write "www.1234.com" the field gives me an error "Not include emails or Urls" So far so good

Problem is when I write `www.1234.com` and give a space after ".com" and a backspace, The field is not in error anymore and let me submit `www.1234.com`.

Comment: If your regex flavors supports a single line modifier, use that and replace all your `[\s\S]` with `.`s

Comment: Hi, already replace, but I have 6 fields on the form and now all gives me errors

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to detect the presence of a group of keywords inside a string using a regex, you could use this:

```
/www|http|@|\.com|\.pt|co\.uk/i
```

If any matches are found, you know one or more of your keywords has been found. I'm not sure this is the approach I would use, but it always depends on the requirements and how strict you need to be.

Comment: I try return this.optional(element) || /^ www|http|@|\.com|\.pt|co\.uk+$/i.test(value); and doesen´t work

Comment: @RAN - Leave out the ^ and $. You are simply trying to see if the words in the regex are present in the string. So use: /www|http|@|\.com|\.pt|co\.uk/i

Comment: Already try some but it doesen't work "return this.optional(element) || /www|http|@|\.com|\.pt|co\.uk/i.test(value);"

Comment: @RAN - Since you were looking for negative lookaheads you'll have to change your code to :   return this.optional(element) || !/www|http|@|\.com|\.pt|co\.uk/i.test(value);

Comment: If your code is accessible on the Internet sure. If not, you could always publish a sample on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Can you test here? mxclass.info/inserir "admin:test password:test" thank you

Comment: Are you sure you got that URL right? I can't read Spanish very well.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle link to an example using this regex: http://jsfiddle.net/gagnonfr/uYcdT/

Comment: Thank you, I go try this jsfiddle.net/gagnonfr/uYcdT